# Searching an item in a k-d tree

Tags: search, tree, lisp, common-lisp

I am developing a k-d tree in Lisp. I am writing a function that allows me to search a node in the k-d tree. This function is defined as follows:

```
(defmethod find-node ((kdt kdtree) target &key (key #'value) (test #'equal))
  (unless (null (root kdt))
    (find-node (root kdt) target :key key :test test)))

(defmethod find-node ((node kdnode) target &key (key #'value) (test #'equal))
  (format t "Testing node ~a~%" (value node))
  (format t "Result is ~a~%" (funcall test (funcall key node) target))
  (if (funcall test (funcall key node) target)
      node
      (progn
        (unless (null (left node))
          (find-node (left node) target :key key :test test))
        (unless (null (right node))
          (find-node (right node) target :key key :test test)))))
```

I build up a tree with the following data: `'((2 3) (5 4) (9 6) (4 7) (8 1) (7 2))`. So now, I am using this function to find the node `'(2 3)`.

```
(find-node kdt '(2 3))
```

With the `format` statements, I get this output:

```
Testing node (7 2)
Result is NIL
Testing node (5 4)
Result is NIL
Testing node (2 3)
Result is T
Testing node (4 7)
Result is NIL
Testing node (9 6)
Result is NIL
Testing node (8 1)
Result is NIL
NIL
```

So, as you can see, the node is found since the result of the test is `T`, however, the search continues and the result is `NIL`. Why doesn't this function return the node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to directly return a result, when you find something.

Use the following example to improve your code:

```
(defun find-it (item list)
  (labels ((find-it-aux (item list)
             (when list
               (if (eql item (first list))
                   (return-from find-it (first list))
                 (find-it-aux item (rest list))))))
    (find-it-aux item list)))

CL-USER 89 > (find-it 1 '(2 3 1 5))
1

CL-USER 90 > (find-it 1 '(2 3 5))
NIL
```

or

```
(defun find-it (item list)
  (catch 'found-it
    (find-it-aux item list)))

(defun find-it-aux (item list)
  (when list
    (if (eql item (first list))
        (throw 'found-it (first list))
      (find-it-aux item (rest list)))))


CL-USER 91 > (find-it 1 '(2 3 1 5))
1

CL-USER 92 > (find-it 1 '(2 3 5))
NIL
```

Comment: I prefer the first solution :).

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify things a little, and stop searching once you find an item, by defining a method for `nil` nodes and using `or`:

```
(defmethod find-node ((empty null) target &key &allow-other-keys)
  nil)

(defmethod find-node ((node kdnode) target &key (key #'value) (test #'equal))
  (if (funcall test (funcall key node) target)
      node
      (or (find-node (left node) target :key key :test test)
          (find-node (right node) target :key key :test test))))
```

You could combine this with Rainer Joswig's answer, of course. For example, you could define an `:around` method for `kdnode`:

```
(defvar *searching* nil)

(defmethod find-node :around ((x kdnode) target &key &allow-other-keys)
  (if *searching*
      (let ((result (call-next-method)))
        (when result
          (throw 'found result)))
      (let ((*searching* t))
        (catch 'found
          (call-next-method)))))
```

You could also place the `catch` block explicitly in the code. If you are sure you never initiate a search on a `kdnode` but always on `kdtree` instances, then you can put the `catch` around `kdtree` instead and get rid of the special variable `*searching*`.

*Note that this example is only here to demonstrate methods. It makes the code a little bit "too clever"; I would probably implement the throw/catch behavior explicitly in practice.*

Answer (score 0):

The function keeps on testing nodes because it is recursive. If you descend left (`find-node (left node) ...`), than the search in the right branch is put on the stack (`find-node (right node) ...`). So, the nodes being tested are all because of the recursion. One way to solve this is to rewrite the function like this:

```
(defmethod find-node ((node kdnode) target &key (key #'value) (test #'equal))
  (let ((left (unless (null (left node))
                (find-node (left node) target :key key :test test)))
        (right (unless (null (right node))
                 (find-node (right node) target :key key :test test)))
        (this (funcall test (funcall key node) target)))
    (if this
        node
        (if left
            left
            right))))
```

Comment: This is traversing the whole tree rather than returning as soon as it finds the target.

Comment: @jkiiski This is just one solution that indeed will traverse the whole tree. Better solutions are always welcome of course.